# I'm using ScrollMenu for displaying the card Component Horizontally but the result displayed is vertical which is same without using ScrollMenu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This code display the **ExerciseCard** and **bodyParts** component horizontally but the output generated is displayed vertically which was same without using **ScrollMenu**

The function for **HorizontalScrollBar** is :

```
const HorizontalScrollBar = ({ data, bodyParts, setBodyPart, bodyPart }) => (
  <ScrollMenu LeftArrow={LeftArrow} RightArrow={RightArrow}>
    {data.map((item) => (
      <Box
        key={item.id || item}
        itemId={item.id || item}
        title={item.id || item}
        m="0 40px"
      >
        {bodyParts ? (
          <BodyPart item={item} setBodyPart={setBodyPart} bodyPart={bodyPart} />
        ) : (
          <ExerciseCard exercise={item} />
        )}
      </Box>
    ))}
  </ScrollMenu>
);
```

The dependency I've used to display the cards horizontally is :

```
import { ScrollMenu } from "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu";
```

I've also installed the below dependency in **package.JSON**

```
`"react-horizontal-scrolling-menu": "^4.1.0",`
```

Expected Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/poE7i.png

resultant output I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AnyN.png

Comment: Please share a GitHub repo or CodeSandbox with your code so we can inspect it.

Comment: https://github.com/Atinsoni/Fitness_Club

Comment: I am not able to run this code, because it uses too many legacy dependencies that aren't compatible with React 18 (along with many that require React 18).

Comment: Can you suggest what should I do to make it right.

Comment: You need to only use dependencies that are compatible with React 18+ (which would be ideal), or else only use those that work with React 17 and below.